# Lightning Web Component not loading while using Lightning-Input with Wrapper class variable

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to build a simple Lightning Web component to allow capturing both parent and child record details on single form. To explain i am taking an example of capturings single Account and Contact details on a single form.

As we cannot have attributes with default initialization like in AURA i have created a wrapper class holding the reference variable to Account and COntact objects as below.

```
public class Account_Contact_Wrapper {

    @AuraEnabled
    public Contact con{ 
        public get;
        public set;

   }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Account acc{ 

        public get;
        public set;

   }

    //default constructor to initiate class level variables

    public Account_Contact_Wrapper() {
        this.con = new Contact(FirstName='',LastName='');
        this.acc = new Account();

    }
}
```

I have created a apex controller which will initiate this wrapper class and return to a wire function call.

```
public class Account_Contact_Capturing_Controller {


//method to initiate wrapper class to pass on to LWC component 

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public  static Account_Contact_Wrapper initiateAccountContact() {

    return new Account_Contact_Wrapper();

}

}
```

I am calling this controller method from Lightning Web component controller using wire as a function.

```
import { LightningElement, track ,wire} from 'lwc';
import initiateAccountContact from '@salesforce/apex/Account_Contact_Capturing_Controller.initiateAccountContact';

export default class test_Component_not_to_deploy extends LightningElement {
    @track accountContact;

    @wire(initiateAccountContact)
    initiateAccountContact({data, error}){

        if(data){
            this.accountContact = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        else if (error) {

            this.error = error;
            this.accountContact = undefined;
        }
    }


}
```

On console.log as well i see the `data` is successfully set from the wire function, but when i try to refer the variables in html the component is not rendering at all.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="test_Component_not_to_deploy" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input label="Name" value={accountContact.con.Name} ></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

But if i remove the variable binding in the value tag on lightning-input tag the component is loading successfully.

Below one is working:

```
        <lightning-input label="Name" value=""></lightning-input>
```

But if i try binding variable like below the component is not loading

```
        <lightning-input label="Name" value={accountContact.con.Name} ></lightning-input>
```

Is there anything missing in above logic, or is there any other way i can achieve initializing my wrapper class? As my form will be used to capture data from multiple objects i cannot go with lightning edit forms.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not initializing the objects with 'properties'. Do as below:

```
public Account_Contact_Wrapper() {
    this.con = new Contact(FirstName='',LastName='');
    this.acc = new Account(Name='');
}
```

**Added**

Con does not have Name and so throwing error. Check in wrapper.

> As we cannot have attributes with default initialization like in AURA

Not correct.

you can initialize in lwc as

`@track account = { Name:'' };`

Comment: Thanks, i actually have initialized the properties as well, still the same issue.

Comment: you need to update the code in question to understand better

Comment: thanks @salesforcesas , i have updated my question and i see the issue is not with adding the tag          <template if:true={reporterDetails}>, I am still checking why is thig tag required and once i find the need of this tag will post a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know Salesforce says the @track is a decorator to track changes deeper on the object

> To tell the framework to observe changes to the properties of an object, decorate the field with @track.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators

also here they affirm it:

> When manipulating complex types like objects and arrays, you must create a new object and assign it to the field for the change to be detected.
> To avoid such issues when working with complex objects, use the @track decorator to deeply tracks mutations made to the field value.

But also in the same documentation:

> However, the framework doesn't observe mutations made to complex objects, such as objects inheriting from Object, class instances, Date, Set, or Map.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields

In other words, the mutation of the object is not being observed.

you have two ways to solve your problem:

First way:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="test_Component_not_to_deploy" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <template if:true={accountContact}
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Name" value={accountContact.con.Name} >. 
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track ,wire} from 'lwc';
import initiateAccountContact from '@salesforce/apex/Account_Contact_Capturing_Controller.initiateAccountContact';

export default class test_Component_not_to_deploy extends LightningElement {
    
    @wire(initiateAccountContact)
    wiredInitiateAccountContact; //name changed, you still can use in the function way
    
    get accountContact() {
        return this.wiredInitiateAccountContact?.data
    }
}
```

The second way is to get each field individually:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="test_Component_not_to_deploy" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input label="Name" value={contactName} >. 
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track ,wire} from 'lwc';
import initiateAccountContact from '@salesforce/apex/Account_Contact_Capturing_Controller.initiateAccountContact';

export default class test_Component_not_to_deploy extends LightningElement {

    @wire(initiateAccountContact)
    wiredInitiateAccountContact; //name changed, you still can use in the function way
    
    get contactName() {
        return this.wiredInitiateAccountContact?.data?.con?.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: just saw this question is really old ;o